# Issues unlocking cells in Excel workbook

Tags: excel, vba

The following code is in the "ThisWorkBook" module however am having issues unlocking particular cells. I am unable to edit the cells in the ranges below.

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Protect Password:="Password01", UserInterFaceOnly:=True, AllowSorting:=True, AllowFiltering:=True
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C6:C5000").Locked = False
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E6:E5000").Locked = False
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("G6:G5000").Locked = False
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("I6:I5000").Locked = False
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("K6:K5000").Locked = False
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("M6:M5000").Locked = False
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("O6:O5000").Locked = False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only change properties of locked cells (including the Lock flag) if the sheet is NOT protected.  Your code protects the sheet first, then tries to change the cells.

Try this:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Unprotect Password:="Password01" ' unprotect, so you can make changes
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C6:C5000").Locked = False
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E6:E5000").Locked = False
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("G6:G5000").Locked = False
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("I6:I5000").Locked = False
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("K6:K5000").Locked = False
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("M6:M5000").Locked = False
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("O6:O5000").Locked = False
' protect after changes have been made
Sheets("Sheet1").Protect Password:="Password01", UserInterFaceOnly:=True, AllowSorting:=True, AllowFiltering:=True
```